# Interface extension and type generics gives "Type argument is not within its bounds"

Tags: kotlin, generics

```kotlin
interface A<T> {
    fun get(): T
}
abstract class C<T: A<K>, K: Any>

class AImpl : A<AImpl> {
    override fun get() = this
}
class CImplA : C<AImpl, AImpl>()
```

In the snippet above, I created:

- a simple interface `A` that provides a function to convert the implementing class to another type; and
- an abstract class `C` that accepts both `A` and its type parameter as type parameters.

and two implementations:

- an implementation of the interface `A` that returns the same object; and
- an implementation of the abstract class `C` that correctly accepts `AImpl` as both type parameters.

**Note**: The first interface and the abstract class can be considered part of a library, and cannot be modified.

My goal is to prevent the explicit override of the `get()` function for each class `X` that implements `A<X>`. To achieve this I tried creating another interface:

```kotlin
interface B : A<B> {
    override fun get() = this
}
```

but the compiler complains when I try to use this interface:

```kotlin
class BImpl : B
class CImplB : C<BImpl, BImpl>()
//               ^^^^^ -> Type argument is not within its bounds.
//                        Expected: A<BImpl>
//                        Found: BImpl
```

Is this a compiler limitation, is it due to type erasure in some way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `BImpl` is an `A<B>`, not an `A<BImpl>`. For this to work you'd have to define `A` as `interface A<in T>`, but this won't let you compile because T appears in out position in `get`. Check variance in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html).